# Expand a range of float numbers ? (keeping a uniform distribution)

Tags: range

> Expand a random range from 0-6 to 0-7. Given a function rand6() that
>   returns a random float in the range [0,6] with a uniform distribution,
>   write a function that returns a random float in the range [0,7] using
>   only rand6() and keeping an uniform distribution.

Since we're working with float numbers, can i just do the following ?

```
x = rand6() / 6 * 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. Your distribution will be scaled as well